# Make Leaflet polyline bold by hover?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, jquery

I have a Leaflet map that I show streets and also there is an unordered list of street names in the same page with map. What I want to do is when mouse cursor hovers on a street name in the list, the poly-line which belongs to that street should be bold.

As far as I know, there is no method listed for Leaflet like that by default but there are options for poly-lines for styling and mine could be shown as below:

```
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {weight: 6}).addTo(map);
```

How can I apply the bold styling to my poly-lines on a hover event?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Please check out our short tour->https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour to learn about our focused Q&A format. Also when asking questions regarding code, please provide what you've tried to do so far, so we can help you from there (NOTE: 1 line of code doesn't count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the id of each street in the list to be able to make a link between the list and the map when hovering. Then use Jquery to create the hovering function and .setStyle() to change the width of the streets.

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/atsh7kv9/5/

**Complete code**

HTML

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;"></div>
<p>Street names</p>
<div id="list"></div>
```

CSS

```
.streetName:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

JS

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([48.21924, 16.3967], 13);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var url = "https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/vienna-streets.geojson"

var streets;
var normalStyle = {weight: 0.5, color:'red'};
var boldStyle ={weight: 10, color:'yellow'};

$.getJSON(url,function(d){
    console.log(d)
    // adding each name in list
    for (var i in d.features){
        $("#list").append("<b class='streetName' id='"+d.features[i].id+"'>"+d.features[i].properties.name+"</b>, ")
    }
    //creating layer
     streets = L.geoJSON(d)
     .setStyle(normalStyle)
     .addTo(map);

    // hovering function
    $(".streetName").mouseover(function(e){
      var id = $(this)[0].id
      streets.eachLayer(function (layer) {  
        if(layer.feature.id == id) {    
          layer.setStyle(boldStyle) 
          console.log(id)
        }
      });
    })
    $(".streetName").mouseout(function(e){
      var id = $(this)[0].id
      streets.eachLayer(function (layer) {  
        if(layer.feature.id == id) {    
          layer.setStyle(normalStyle) 
          console.log(id)
        }
      });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `bold` style for polylines, just `weight` option, which is width of polyline in pixels.

If you want to change polyline style to 'bold', you have to increase it's width, let's say from 6 to 8 pixels. You can increase it's width by declaring `mouseover` event catch function, where you can change width of polyline by `setStyle` method.

At the same time you have to save original weight to dummy `mySavedWeight` property (name can be any, as long as it's not in conflict with standard names), which is then used in `mouseout` catch function to return style to original one when mouse leaves polyline. Since there is no `getStyle` method for polyline, width can be saved via `options` property.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {weight: 6}).addTo(map);

polyline.on('mouseover', function() {
  this.mySavedWeight = this.options.weight;
  this.setStyle({
    weight: 8
  });
});

polyline.on('mouseout', function() {
  this.setStyle({
    weight: this.mySavedWeight
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code